# Bootstrap file input not working when deployed

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, iis

I´m using **Bootstrap file input** package, it works locally but fails on production.

[This is how it looks on vs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Aqnx.jpg)

[After deployment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYhFt.jpg)

I have read that might be js files not loading correctly, but cant find a solution yet.

**EDIT**

This is the code:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- canvas-to-blob.min.js is only needed if you wish to resize images before upload.
     This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="/Scripts/plugins/canvas-to-blob.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- sortable.min.js is only needed if you wish to sort / rearrange files in initial preview.
     This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="/Scripts/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- purify.min.js is only needed if you wish to purify HTML content in your preview for HTML files.
     This must be loaded before fileinput.min.js -->
<script src="/Scripts/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<!-- the main fileinput plugin file -->
<script src="/Scripts/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<!-- bootstrap.js below is needed if you wish to zoom and view file content 
     in a larger detailed modal dialog -->
<link href="/Content/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="input-44" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Cargar fotos</label>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
        <input id="input-44" name="input44[]" type="file" multiple class="file-loading">
        <script>
            $(document).on('ready', function () {
                $("#input-44").fileinput({
                    uploadUrl: '/file-upload-batch/2',
                    'showUpload': false,
                    maxFilePreviewSize: 10240,
                    fileActionSettings: {
                        showUpload: false,
                        indicatorNew: ''
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </div>
</div> </asp:Content>
```

Comment: Can you share some of your code so we can get a better idea of what's going on?

Comment: Sure, i just did.

Comment: `<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`  should have leading `https:`?

Comment: Did Michael's suggestion fix the issue?

Comment: Nope, still looks the same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading and trying to fix this all day, i decided to **view page source** of both scenarios (development/production) and compared them.

On development, this line `<script src="/Scripts/fileinput.min.js"></script>`
 is a link for seeing the code of that file. When deployed, the same line is a not working link, it throws [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIPHs.jpg) and i noticed that it was missing the name of my project between the ip(192.168.0.145) and the path /Scripts.

If i try this `<script src="/MyProject/Scripts/fileinput.min.js"></script>` i got it working on production but on development failed cause then it was aiming to *192.168.0.145/MyProject/MyProject/Scripts/fileinput.min.js* and this path doesn't exist either.

**SOLUTION**

Just add two points at the beginning, like this:

```
<script src="../Scripts/plugins/canvas-to-blob.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/plugins/sortable.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/plugins/purify.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/fileinput.min.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap-fileinput/css/fileinput.min.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Hope this help someone else in the future.